# making a design responsive using media query

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm new to css. I'm trying to make a design, responsive only by using `media query`. For me the design is getting responsive, but there is some problem
that you can see in the image. Please say your suggestions.

[image: My image]

link of the code:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yLwtpnze/)

Comment: Where exactly is the issue. The image got missed. Include the media script you used and a description of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Can you edit your post and add the html code for your header?

Comment: By the way, min-device-width and max-device-width are deprecated. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40media/device-width).

Comment: i  am getting error when trying to insert html code

Comment: Follow the instructions or try to put your code in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 0):

I put the code into a **[Codepen](https://codepen.io/SirExotic/pen/zjJXMb)** because it's easier to view and debug.

You forgot to do a few things:

- give `body {height 100%;}`
- give `.container {height: 100%}`

The media-queries work as they should, too.